# Java Regex names (with spaces and special characters)

Tags: java, regex, special-characters

I am building a program for a French soccer federation.

The names should be able to consist of "letters, spaces, ', - , è and é".

But I am having trouble finding a good regex for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if there is no other rules for names, this piece of code should work:

```
String name = "namé";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z'èé\\s\\-]*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(name);
System.out.println(matcher.matches());
```